# Calculating positive non-integer power of negative base

Tags: c++

To my knowledge

`(-1)^1.8 = [(-1)^18]^0.1 = [1]^0.1 = 1`

Hope I am not making a silly mistake.

`std::pow(-1, 1.8)` results in `nan`. Also, due to [this link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow):

> If base is finite and negative and exp is finite and non-integer, a domain error occurs and a range error may occur.

Is there a workaround to calculate the above operation with C++?

Comment: From a mathemetical point of view, `(-1)^1.8` is not defined. If `x` is real, then `a^x = exp (x ln a)`

Comment: In the arbitrary case, `pow(-1, r)` where `r` is a real number will likely be a complex number, so the result is outside of the real domain (thus the `nan` for a real number function). You'll need to use a [C++ complex number class library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/pow) if you're interested in complex numbers.

Comment: 1.8=18/10=9/5=36/20... why would you prefer 18/10?  why would you apply the 18 before the 1/10?  (and I does not start with the question of the exact representation of 1.8 which is not possible in the most common floating point formats).

Comment: Relevant discussion: [How do you compute negative numbers to fractional powers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/317528/35714).

Comment: pow is for real positive numbers, not for negatives

Answer (score 0):

`std::pow` from `<cmath>` is for real numbers. The exponentiation (power) function of real numbers is not defined for negative bases.

Wikipedia says:

> [Real exponents with negative bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Real_exponents_with_negative_bases)
>
> Neither the logarithm method nor the rational exponent method can be used to define b<sup>r</sup> as a real number for a negative real number b and an arbitrary real number r. Indeed, e<sup>r</sup> is positive for every real number r, so ln(b) is not defined as a real number for b ≤ 0.
>
> The rational exponent method cannot be used for negative values of b
>   because it relies on continuity. The function f(r) = b<sup>r</sup> has a unique
>   continuous extension from the rational numbers to the real numbers
>   for each b > 0. But when b < 0, the function f is not even continuous
>   on the set of rational numbers r for which it is defined.
>
> For example, consider b = −1. The nth root of −1 is −1 for every odd
>   natural number n. So if n is an odd positive integer, (−1)<sup>(m/n)</sup> = −1
>   if m is odd, and (−1)<sup>(m/n)</sup> = 1 if m is even. Thus the set of rational
>   numbers q for which (−1)<sup>q</sup> = 1 is dense in the rational numbers, as is
>   the set of q for which (−1)<sup>q</sup> = −1. This means that the function (−1)<sup>q</sup>
>   is not continuous at any rational number q where it is defined.
>
> On the other hand, arbitrary complex powers of negative numbers b can
>   be defined by choosing a complex logarithm of b.
>
> [Powers of complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Powers_of_complex_numbers)
>
> Complex powers of positive reals are defined via e<sup>x</sup> as in section
>   Complex exponents with positive real bases above [omitted from this quote]. These are continuous
>   functions.
>
> Trying to extend these functions to the general case of noninteger
>   powers of complex numbers that are not positive reals leads to
>   difficulties. Either we define discontinuous functions or multivalued
>   functions. Neither of these options is entirely satisfactory.
>
> The rational power of a complex number must be the solution to an
>   algebraic equation. Therefore, it always has a finite number of
>   possible values. For example, w = z<sup>1/2</sup> must be a solution to the
>   equation w<sup>2</sup> = z. But if w is a solution, then so is −w, because (−1)<sup>2</sup>
>   = 1. A unique but somewhat arbitrary solution called the principal value can be chosen using a general rule which also applies for
>   nonrational powers.
>
> Complex powers and logarithms are more naturally handled as single
>   valued functions on a Riemann surface. Single valued versions are
>   defined by choosing a sheet. The value has a discontinuity along a
>   branch cut. Choosing one out of many solutions as the principal value
>   leaves us with functions that are not continuous, and the usual rules
>   for manipulating powers can lead us astray.

So, before calculating the result, you must first choose what you are calculating. The C++ standard library has in `<complex>` a function template `std::complex<T> pow(const complex<T>& x, const T& y)`, which is specified to calculate (through definition of `cpow` in C standard):

> The cpow functions  compute  the  complex power  function x<sup>y</sup>, with  a  branch  cut  for  the first parameter along the negative real axis.

For (-1)<sup>1.8</sup>, the result would be e<sup>-(iπ)/5</sup> ≈ 0.809017 + 0.587785i.

This is not what you expected as result. There is no exponentiation function in the C++ standard library that would calculate the result that you want.